# How to calculate actual memory used by string variable?

Tags: string, delphi, memory

Strings in Delphi locating in dynamic memory.

How to calculate actual memory (in bytes) used by `string` variable?

I know the string must store some additional information, at least reference count and length, but how many bytes it uses except characters?

```
var
  S: string;
```

*Delphi 2010, XE, XE2 used*

Comment: The answer is documented in the official documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio

Comment: @David - The docs will lead to a wrong conclusion in 64 bits, see my comment to opc0de's answer.

Comment: @Sertac I have no computer right now. Is the difference between 32 and 64 bit simply an extra 4 bytes of padding? So the length is still a 32 bit field?

Comment: @David - Yes, there's a `_Padding: LongInt;` field in a `CPUX64` define. Length is still Longint.

Comment: @sertac Thanks. It would be great if you could write an answer that was accurate to compete with the misinformation that we presently have.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The layout on 32 bit UNICODE DELPHI taken from official Embarcadero documentation is like this:

[image: UNICODE DELPHI]

Note that there's an additional longint field in the 64 bit version for 16 byte alignment. The `StrRec` record in 'system.pas' looks like this:

```
StrRec = packed record
{$IF defined(CPUX64)}
  _Padding: LongInt; // Make 16 byte align for payload..
{$IFEND}
  codePage: Word;
  elemSize: Word;
  refCnt: Longint;
  length: Longint;
end;
```

The payload is always 2*(Length+1) in size. The overhead is 12 or 16 bytes, for 32 or 64 bit targets. Note that the actual memory block may be larger than needed as determined by the memory manager.

Finally, there has been much mis-information in this question. On 64 bit targets, strings are still indexed by 32 bit signed integers.

Comment: There was some weirdness, either the RefCount or the Length was limited to 32 bits and there was 32 bit reserved data. (Can't find the reference right now).

Comment: The actual memory usage is larger as FastMM rounds the string size up (to 16, IIRC) for faster string resizing (s := s + 'a').

Comment: This applies to pre-Unicode Delphi. It is not true in Unicode Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan help me improve the answer. Don't know what is different in unicode

Comment: Read the doc link in my comment to the Q?

Comment: Documentation does not mention the *padding*, see 'StrRec' in system.pas or comments to Gamecat's answer.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz feel free to edit my post or post your own answer. I don't like to post things that I don't understand.

Comment: @Gabr: not AFAIK. Strings, even in 64 bit, can't be larger than 4GB. ISTR that they even can't be larger than 2GB.

Comment: @opc0de: what I see now (probably after some editing by others?) looks fine. It mentions the fields in 32 bit and 64 bit, and that the actual size can be a few bytes larger depending on the memory manager and on the actual size of the string. IIRC, smaller strings have a smaller allocation resolution than large ones.

Comment: re: padding - Sorry for not being specific enough - this 'padding' is automatic for all FastMM-allocated objects

Comment: re: padding - can't find a fresh information about that, here's an old and potentially outdated link: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/10/765477.html

Comment: @Rudy, you are correct, strings cannot be over 6 GB. Just tested.

Comment: @gabr: 6GB? That comes as a bit unexpected.

Comment: @gabr: the largest size I can get, in 64 bit mode, is: `SetLength(S, MaxInt div 2 - 9)`. That is a max. size of 2147483644. Any value higher than that gives me an integer overflow error.

Comment: 6 GB was just a type, I meant 4 GB

Answer (score 7):

For `String` specifically, you can use `SysUtils.ByteLength()` to get the byte length of the character data, and if not zero then increment the result by `SizeOf(System.StrRec)` (which is the header in front of the character data) and `SizeOf(Char)` (for the null-terminator that is not included in the length), eg:

```
var 
  S: string;
  len: Integer;
begin
  S := ...;
  len := ByteLength(s);
  if len > 0 then Inc(len, SizeOf(StrRec) + SizeOf(Char));
end;
```

On the other hand, if you want to calculate the byte size of other string types, like `AnsiString`, `AnsiString(N)` (such as `UTF8String`), `RawByteString`, etc, you need to use `System.StringElementSize()` instead, eg:

```
var 
  S: SomeStringType;
  len: Integer;
begin
  S := ...;
  len := Length(S) * StringElementSize(S);
  if len > 0 then Inc(len, SizeOf(StrRec) + StringElementSize(s));
end;
```

In either case, the reason you only increment the length if the string has characters in it is because empty strings do not take up any memory at all, they are `nil` pointers.

Comment: @Remy-Where is StrRec declared in Delphi XE? StrRec is unknown is I just use 'System.StrRec'

Comment: `StrRec` is declared in the `implementation` section of the `System` unit, so it is not directly accessible. You would have to redeclare it in your own code if you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question:

> How to calculate actual memory (in bytes) used by string variable?

```
MemSize = Overhead + CharSize * (Length + 1)

CharSize = 1    // for Ansi strings
CharSize = 2    // for Unicode strings
Overhead = 8    // for 32 bit strings
Overhead = 16   // for 64 bit strings
```

Comment: 16 bytes overhead for a string in 64 bit? That's quite a lot :-O Unicode already doubled the string sizes and now for short strings this gets even worse...why do 64 bit strings have more overhead? No need for 64 bit reference counts and lengths...

Comment: @Smasher - However that's correct. In 64 bits there's an additional LongInt to align to 16bytes.

Comment: @Smasher, the length is a 8 byte pointer, the refcount is 4, but there is 4 byte reserved space. So the total is 16. (I got this information on a release meeting by Embarcadero, but found no reference on the web).

Comment: No, length is always a 32 bit field. This answer is wrong and your comments contain mis-information.

Comment: David is right. Length is still a 32 bit signed integer. For something that is supposed to contain text, that is big enough. And Overhead is 12 byte (not 8 byte) for strings in the latest 32 bit versions, just as David explained.